# php mysql search query wildcard problem

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

If I search for LENA, I only want to get results where LENA is one word and not part of a word like Lenason or Anna-Lena or Malena

How do I write such a query, not

```
"select * from users where name like '%LENA%'"
```

What should it be instead?

Comment: I see you un-accepted my answer; what went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Use this one:

```
select * from users where name like '% LENA %' OR name like 'LENA %' OR name like '% LENA' OR name like 'LENA'
```

Try it, it will work, and too simple with 2 spaces at start and end.
Its long but fast query. You can also use Full Text Search, Concat, Regex ... but for me, I like simple, just add some space before %.

However, you can try shorter but slower query:

```
SELECT * FROM users  WHERE name REGEXP '(^|\s+)LENA($|\s+)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT fields 
  FROM users
 WHERE name REGEXP '(^|\s+)LENA($|\s+)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off looking into [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html?PHPSESSID=9416870780d93e2f1379d1bb8cc29b26) for this.

Otherwise I think you're stuck doing something like this

```
"select * from users WHERE CONCAT(' ',name, ' ') like '% LENA %'"
```

Which will be pretty inefficient as it requires a full table scan.

Comment: **Full Text Search** would do the trick, but your "something like" query will give identical results as the original (but with more cpu overhead).

Comment: @Bob - You were right that there was an issue with my query but not the one you were thinking of I think. I forgot that you needed to use `CONCAT` for string concatenation in MySQL rather than `+`. The reason for concatenating spaces is that names where `lena` is the first, last or only word wouldn't match the where clause `name like '% LENA %'` without this.

Comment: Looked up '%' in the MySQL manual and it also matches `zero characters`. This was the flaw in my logic.